# Check out new maven module from svn with m2e plugin

Tags: eclipse, maven-3, m2eclipse

I have im my current workspace the parent module and the children, each as a maven module. A new child module is available on svn, how do I get the new module's source code without getting the full project?

Comment: Synchronize and update the parent project ?

Comment: tried that... didnt't work. under the parent module i see the new module, but i cannot see it in my workspace as a module itself

Comment: You can do a right click on the new module and select import. you should import it as a maven project, and would see it in your workspace